# Cleaning column value when starting with

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[.1, 2, 3], [.4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]),
                   columns=['col1', 'b', 'c'])
```

out:

```
   col1  b   c
0   0.1 2.0 3.0
1   0.4 5.0 6.0
2   7.0 8.0 9.0
```

When a value begins with a '.'/point,  I want to remove it. But only if it starts with a point / '.'.

I've tried the following:

```
s = df['col1']
df['col1'] = s.mask(df['col1'].str.startswith('.',na=False),s.str.replace(".",""))
```

desired output:

```
   col1  b   c
0   1   2.0 3.0
1   4   5.0 6.0
2   7.0 8.0 9.0
```

However this does not work. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

since you have numerical values, You can multiply 10 and replace with a condition:

```
df.mul(10).mask(df.ge(1),df)
#df['col1'] = df['col1'].mul(10).mask(df['col1'].ge(1),df['col1']) for 1 column
```

---

```
   col1    b    c
0   1.0  2.0  3.0
1   4.0  5.0  6.0
2   7.0  8.0  9.0
```

Answer (score 0):

use boolean masking and create a mask:

```
mask=df['col1'].astype(str).str.startswith('0.')
```

Finally make use of that mask:

```
df.loc[mask,'col1']=df.loc[mask,'col1'].astype(str).str.lstrip('0.').astype(float)
```

Now if you print `df` you will get your desired output:

```
    col1    b       c
0   1.0     2.0     3.0
1   4.0     5.0     6.0
2   7.0     8.0     9.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Via NumpPy `np.where()`:

```
df['col1'] = np.where(df<1, df*10, df)
```

df contents:

```
    col1      b       c
0   1.0     2.0     3.0
1   4.0     5.0     6.0
2   7.0     8.0     9.0
```